# BLE: LE Secure Connection with Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

We're talking about BLE. Right now Im using the Plugin.BLE library and it's working quite fine. Now Im in the need of using the **LE Secure Connection** (with the "just works" method) in order to send/receive **encrypted** data.

I've read lots of documentation about how the protocol works, but have no idea of how actually implementing it in Xamarin and wasn't able to find **anything** on this.
With the Plugin.BLE one can take advantage of a very simple APIs to connect to a Device. 
Is there **any library** that provides similar simplicity and enabling an LE Secure Connection?

If not, how can I connect in Android & iOS to a BLE device using a secure channel?

Thank you very much

Comment: This question is off topic.  See #4 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  I recommend asking a specific question explaining what you have done so far to solve your problem.

Comment: Im sorry. I didn't nothing to solve the problem because I didnt find almost any help on that.

Answer (score 1):

The pairing is handled by the Bluetooth stack and not by the application, so you can't affect this in any way. However, from Marshmallow and onward, BLE pairing will use Secure Connections as long as the second device supports it. Not sure about iOS.

Comment: thanks! Do you mean that as long as I connect to a device (using whatever library) in theory the BLE stack should activate at least the SSP "just works" mode? thank you

Comment: "... will use Secure Connections (SC) as long as the second device supports it" -> @Emil: do you mean if device support BLE SC, then it will SC. Otherwise it will choose a different pairing mode. So, how do we know which device supports the SC mode?